Recomposition does not occur despite the mutableStateOf variable being changed
I want to make buttons randomly change color on click. To this end, I introduce a dummy mutable state variable flag, that is being changed on the click event. Yet, no recomposition occurs afterwards:
@Composable
fun Cell(modifier: Modifier){
    val color = listOf(Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Black).shuffled()[0]
    var flag by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val bc = ButtonColors(color, Color.White, Color.White, Color.White)
    Button(onClick={flag=true}, modifier=modifier, colors = bc,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp) ) {}
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
fun FlowTable(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val rows = 3
    val columns = 3
    FlowRow(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
        maxItemsInEachRow = rows
    ) {
        val itemModifier = Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .height(80.dp)
            .weight(1f)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .background(Color.Blue)
        repeat(rows * columns) {
            Cell(modifier)
        }
    }

}

However, according to the debugger, the onClick event occurs, and just right after the event the program executes the var flag by remember { mutableStateOf(false) } line, yet it does not proceed any further (neither does it execute previous lines)!

what is your expectation?

base on your code. you do not understand how state works in jetpack compose you should read it here https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/state

The issue is that the flag state variable is updated, but it's not used anywhere in your Cell composable. In compose, a state variable needs to be read somewhere in the composable for recomposition to happen when it changes.
To make the button change color on click, create a randomColor state variable. This variable store a random color, and then update this variable with a new random color when the button is clicked.
Here’s how you can modify your code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    FlowTable(name = "table name")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun Cell(modifier: Modifier){
    val colors = listOf(Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Black)

    var randomColor by remember {
        mutableStateOf(colors.random())
    }

    Button(
        onClick= { randomColor = colors.random() },
        modifier=modifier.background(color = randomColor),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors().copy(containerColor = randomColor)
    ) {}
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
fun FlowTable(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val rows = 3
    val columns = 3
    FlowRow(
        modifier = modifier.padding(4.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
        maxItemsInEachRow = rows
    ) {
        repeat(rows * columns) {
            Cell(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .height(80.dp)
                    .weight(1f)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            )
        }
    }
}

Demo:

